# Setting width and height in image

Tags: php, html, css, image, width

I'm currently coding a slide that uses images that are stored in a database.
I would like to know how can i set width and height for the image. Here's my code:

```
<div id="my-slide">
<?php
$resultado = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM slides ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3");

while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado))
{
?>
  <div data-lazy-background="images/<?php echo $fila["slideimg"]; ?>">
    <h5><?php echo $fila["cap"]; ?></h5>
  </div>
<?php
}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: we will need html output and your actual CSS code.

Comment: Do you save the images width and height in the `slides` table? and what's the current output, if you could provide us?

Comment: are you setting the image as div background or you just want to display the image on web page

Answer (score 0):

Set Height and Width between your image Div like

```
<div width="100px" height="100px"  data-lazy-background="images/<?php echo $fila["slideimg"]; ?>">
```

Comment: give class name to div and then apply width and height by css

Comment: Tried that too and nothing :/

Comment: @user3375665 Could you provide what's the output? Do yo save the images height and width in DB?

Comment: Provide the output, how? Show you the website? It's not online yet... And no, i'm not saving width and height in the DB

Comment: @user3375665 Just a screenshot will help; or explain if you see the images in a proper layout?

Comment: Yes i see. But their width or height just won't change. They keep the original dimensions

Comment: I think you are using some specific javascrip/jQuery plugin to show the slider; if that plugin has a documentation it may mention how to make the image size dynamic. You can try `<div style="width:100px; height:100px;" ... >...</div>` but I think your plugin will override it